# C# - Interface generic method constraint to match derived type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, constraints

Let's say I have an interface IA, containing a generic method called Foo.

```
public interface IA {
    int Foo<T>(T otherType);
}
```

I want T to be the same type as the derived class:

```
class A : IA {
    int Foo(A otherType)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried following (syntax error):

```
public interface IA {
    int Foo<T>(T otherType) where T : this;
}
```

How does my constraint need to look like to achieve that?

Comment: Don't think thats possible. The interface cant know what will implement it. This is basically the chicken/egg thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to do it like this:

```
public interface IA<T>
{
    int Foo(T otherType);
}

class A : IA<A>
{
    public int Foo(A otherType)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

It's the only way to enforce the interface member's generic type.